# VB.net Paint Event Multiple Instances - sender object

Tags: vb.net, graphics, load, paint, sender

Got an interesting bug here and I finally tracked down the cause. Issue is, after a couple days of exhaustive trial and error, I've come up empty handed.

So, the part in question about my program, is that these multiple instance of a form are a child of a parent form. There can be several separate instances of the child form at once.

They load up fine, however, the sender object seems to have it wrong. Let's just say we have Form2-1 (first instance). Form2-1 is already open and displaying stuff.

Now we open Form2-2 (second instance of Form2). It loads fine as per checking the "Sender" object of the load event.

Where my problem lies, is that once the load event is completed, it shoots over to the paint event. In the load form, a Object that allows the paint event to draw data and information is given this data and information in the load event.

When it gets to this paint event after loading Form2-2 (2nd instance), the sender object of the paint event is Form2-1 (1st instance). So we're now overwriting everything on the 1st instance that should have been on the 2nd instance.

It will loop through and then paint the 2nd instance, 3rd instance, etc...the load and paint event "sender" is not lining up, causing graphics to be lost. Basically, whatever is the newest instance that is opened, all other previous instances will gain the graphics painted from the newest instance.

Any idea what is going on here?

EDIT: To clarify, the object that gives the data and information to another object (let's call it, Object1 [the giver object]), Object2 (Object that retrieves data from Object1 in load event  [the retriever object]) is used in the paint event; Object1  gets it's data from a subroutine that retrieves information from a file outside of the program.

EDIT2: TempObject, Object1 and Object2 are all of the same structure. Here is snippets from the various subs and events involved:

At this point, Form2-1 is loaded. This Load Event is now at this point loading Form2-2, which it does. Temp Holds backup data which right now is not doing anything. 
In this case, it would be holding Form2-1's data until it takes Object1's data for Form2-2. Object2 takes Object1's data for Form2-2. This Object2 is then passed on to the paint event and the various subs called inside the paintevent use Object2 to draw data and info since Object2 is a PUBLIC declaration of a Structure

```
 Private Sub Form2_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As     
System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
'Document info is in public obj, Object1
'x-fer to this docs info obj Object2
RedimTempObject()
'TempObject = Object1
'*TempObject Used as a backup source of data because when you do certain    
functions in Form2 from
'*ParentForm, VB.Net reads it in a way that Object2 does not have any data.    TempObject fixes this.
    Object2 = Object1
End Sub
```

After it Loads Form2-2, it comes here and the sender reads "Form2-1". At this point if you are breakpoint stepping through, on the program screen will show Form2-1 loaded and painted and barebones stuff of Form2-2 on top

```
 Public Sub frmDoc_Paint(ByVal sender As System.Windows.Forms.Form, ByVal e                           
As PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint
'A few subroutines in here that only take the "e" argument to draw stuff
End Sub
```

Comment: Each form instance has it own private paint event.  The sender argument is telling you which form instance Windows wants/needs to paint.  If one of the forms is overlayed/behind something else, Windows wont try to paint it.  In part it sounds like maybe the 2 forms are maybe trying to draw shared data.  Not much more can be said without the related code.

Comment: Just added an EDIT at the end. Not sure if that helps clarify anything. If you'd like to see the code, what would you like to see? I can give you snippets from the load event and paint event. I can also give you snippets from the subroutine that gives Object1 it's data

Comment: *Not much more can be said without the related code.*

Comment: Everything sounds entirely normal.  Why the first instance uses the wrong data requires consultation with a clairvoyant.  A random guess is that it is using a *static* variable, one that got overwritten when the 2nd instance was created.  Using the VB.NET syntax that allows using the type name instead of an object reference (like Form2.Foo) is quite deadly here.

Comment: Not using any static variables here. Just Object2 that is public in a module, Object1 is Public in a module and TempObject is Public, also in a module

Comment: Those are all static variables :)

Comment: Oh, thought you referring to the "static" declaration. I think I may have just found out my issue. the Object2 was PUBLIC. It should have been PRIVATE. Because Object2 pulls data from outside Form2, Object1 needs to be private, and was public. I could have sworn this was private.

Only reason I found this out was when I was pasting code snippets in here for you guys to look at to help me out. So, thank you very much!

Comment: You mentioning static variables helped me out. Could you make a copy and paste of your comment as an answer so I can mark it as solved, Hans Passant?